# Make clabels less frequent at the map using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am making a map using cartopy in python. I've made the temperature filled contours and needed to add labels over there:

```
projection=ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=25.0, central_latitude=58.0) 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax = plt.axes(projection=projection)
ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=0.5, color='gray', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5)
levels1 = np.linspace(-1, 23, 25)
csf = ax.contourf(lons, lats, thetao[0,0,:,:], levels=levels1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), 
                  cmap='RdYlBu_r', extend='both')
cs = ax.contour(lons, lats, thetao[0,0,:,:], levels=levels1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), 
                  cmap='RdYlBu_r', extend='both', linewidths=0.1)
for text in ax.clabel(cs, colors='black', fontsize=7, fmt='%1.0f'):
    text.set_bbox({'boxstyle': 'square, pad=0.2', 'facecolor': 'white',
                       'alpha': 0.6, 'edgecolor': 'None'})
ax.set_title('Merevee temperatuur ja veetase (cm) '+str(esttimes[0]))
cbar = plt.colorbar(csf, label='T, °C', orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.75, aspect = 25,  fraction=0.05,
                    pad=0.05, ticks=np.linspace(-1, 23, 13), drawedges=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: sst]
In some places clabels are too frequent and it does not look good. Is there any possibility to make clabels less frequent at the map.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to do this automatically, but you could add them manually using `ax.clabel(manual=True)` ...

from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourLabeler.clabel):

> manual  bool or iterable, default: False
>
> If True, contour labels will be placed manually using mouse clicks. Click the first button near a contour to add a label, click
> the second button (or potentially both mouse buttons at once) to
> finish adding labels. The third button can be used to remove the last
> label added, but only if labels are not inline. Alternatively, the
> keyboard can be used to select label locations (enter to end label
> placement, delete or backspace act like the third mouse button, and
> any other key will select a label location).
>
> manual can also be an iterable object of (x, y) tuples. Contour labels will be created as if mouse is clicked at each (x, y) position.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I really need this to be done automatically somehow, as the forecast is going to be shown on the homepage.